# dart language: How to get all the classes available to import?

Tags: dart, import, reflection

Programmatically I want to get all dart files available to import.
How can I achievement this? (programmatically)

Comment: One potential issue with this plan is that packages contains multiple dart files but often only one (or a few) which is actually suppose to be imported. So we cannot just iterate over all available Dart files and automatically import these. Also, if a package have multiple Dart files to import, it can often be because there are some restrictions. E.g. import a specific version if doing web-developer and another file if doing Flutter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In which environment do you want that?

If it's for a single Pub package, ensure that `dart pub get` has been run, then parse the `.dart_tool/package_config.json` file and find the roots of all the packages. Then search through those directories for all `dart` files that are not part files (does not start with `part of ...;`). The rest should be Dart library files which can be imported.

If you only want the packages that can be imported from inside `lib/`, you may want to parse the `pubspec.yaml` file too, so you can ignore the `dev_dependencies`.

Then you may also want to list the available `dart:...` platform libraries. Which are available depends on which platform you compile for. You need to figure that out somehow, then you should just keep a list for each platform.